# program to find index of a substring from a file

Tags: c, string, file-handling

I am trying to find the index at which a substring is present in a file after i copy it into an array

I am suspecting this to have something with matching addresses. If it is, what are the other alternatives?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
            FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            int len, i=0, c=0;
            fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
            len = ftell(fp);                                //number of characters in file
            rewind(fp);
            char ch, arr[len], *p, *q; 
            while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )                 //copy file into arr[len]
            {
                    arr[i] = ch; 
                    i++;
            }
            rewind(fp);
            char a[200];

            while((fgets(a, 200, fp)))              //a contains line from fp
            {
            q=a;                                    //q pointing at base address of a
                    if((p = strstr(a, arr))!=NULL)
                    {
                            while(q!=p)
                            {
                                    c++;
                                    q++;    
                            }
                            printf("c >> %d\n", c);    
                    }
            }
    }
```

Output is not printing anything even when substring is present in file, i am expecting c to print the index of array.

Comment: Once you copy it to the array you don't need to rescan the file, just scan the array

Comment: Note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an `int`. That is actually very important for the `EOF` check.

Comment: As for your problem, now is probably a very good time to learn how to *debug* your programs. Using a debugger you can step through the code, statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: to which substring are you comparing? Looks like you just tacking 200 symbols from file (a array) and compare to entire file content which makes no sense to me

Comment: Please provide simple input and expected output in order to correctly understand what are you trying to acheive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the order of the parameters (besides all other problems):

```
const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
      char * strstr (       char * str1, const char * str2 );

Locate substring
Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of str2 in str1, or a null pointer if str2 is not part of str1.
```

So you'll never find the whole contents of your file in whatever you keep in variable `a`.